# Fail to start effort_controllers/JointVelocityController (ros_controllers)

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.

I managed to make the effort_controllers/JointPositionController successfully works, but some of my joints need to be controlled using the velocity.

When using this type, I get the following error message:

```
gzserver: /home/arnaud/Documents/catkin_ws/src/ros_control/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/joint_state_interface.h:71: double hardware_interface::JointStateHandle::getVelocity() const: Assertion `vel_' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any idea of how to fix this? It looks like a run-time error.

Thx in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4086/fail-to-start-effort_controllers/jointvelocitycontroller-(ros_controllers)/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-08-08**:
Can you post a backtrace? And can you detail what steps you are going through to run Gazebo?

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) on 2013-08-08**:
I am running into the same problem in Gazebo 1.9.0. Where should I post example files so you can see what I'm doing?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-09-15**:
Can you update your original question with the example files?

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) on 2013-09-16**:
Gazebo 1.9.1 manifests the problem differently. See this question to find out how to download my example repo: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4165/jointvelocitycontroller-does-not-work-in-gazebo/

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) on 2013-09-16**:
Ultimately, the problem is this: a JointVelocityController derivative gain of around 0.01 can result in a very large effort. When that effort value is sent to Gazebo, many of the robot's links are moved to the world origin. I am currently adding a joint limit interface to gazebo_ros_control in order to prevent the problem, though a fix for Gazebo's reaction to large efforts would be welcome.

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-09-17**:
Please check my answer below for a full description of the pb, including code and configuration files. This question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unable to reproduce the issue after a recent update. I am still not able to use a velocity controller, this is discuss in the following question:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4102/my-robot-blows-up-when-i-launch-the-controllers/

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) with karma: 316 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0